# Where is the Yam Shel Shlomo's essay on breira printed?

Tags: talmud-gemara, acharonim

I've heard that the [Maharshal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solomon_Luria) wrote a detailed essay on [breira](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breira_(Talmudic_doctrine)).

Where can it be found in his writings? Is it somewhere in the Yam Shel Shlomo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is in the [Yam shel Shlomo to the fifth perek of Bava Kamma](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40932&hilite=fa7832ba-fa72-4686-81ec-05e93a5609aa&st=%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94&pgnum=88)